# How to access variables inside custom knockout binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker

So I'm using this date picker library. http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#knockout

Is there a way for my to grab the value from the handler and save it in my view model? I want to expose the value of `var picker = $(element).data('DateTimePicker');` outside of the handler inside my view model. Is this possible?

```js
/*globals Hilary*/
Hilary.scope('learn').register({
    name: 'DatetimeVM',
    dependencies: ['ko', 'jQuery', 'moment', 'OptionSelectVM'],
    factory: function (ko, $, moment, OptionSelectVM) {
        'use strict';

        return function (date) {
            var self = {
                date: {
                    type: ko.observable(),
                    start: ko.observable(),
                    end: ko.observable()
                }
            };

            if(!ko.bindingHandlers.dateTimePicker) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.dateTimePicker = {
                    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                        var viewOptions = allBindingsAccessor().dateTimePickerOptions || {},
                            options;

                        options = $.extend({
                            inline: true,
                            debug: true
                        }, viewOptions);

                        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

                        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
                        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'dp.change', function (event) {
                            var value = valueAccessor();
                            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                                if (event.date !== null && !(event.date instanceof Date)) {
                                    value(event.date.toDate());
                                } else {
                                    value(event.date);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                            var picker = $(element).data('DateTimePicker');

                            if (picker) {
                                picker.destroy();
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                        var picker = $(element).data('DateTimePicker');

                        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                        if (picker) {
                            var koDate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

                            //in case return from server datetime i am get in this form for example /Date(93989393)/ then fomat this
                            // koDate = (typeof (koDate) !== 'object') ? new Date(parseFloat(koDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))) : koDate

                            picker.date(koDate);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }

            return self;
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! Check out [the custom bindings documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), there's more arguments passed to your binding handler's `init` and `update` function than you're currently using, including a fourth one called `viewModel` for pre Knockout 3.x, and `bindingContext` for 3.x versions.

From the mentioned docs:

> - `viewModel` — This parameter is deprecated in Knockout 3.x. Use `bindingContext.$data` or `bindingContext.$rawData` to access the view model instead.
> - `bindingContext` — An object that holds the binding context available to this element’s bindings. This object includes special properties including `$parent`, `$parents`, and `$root` that can be used to access data that is bound against ancestors of this context.

Beware though, this creates a dependency *from* your handler *to* specific view models, which is typically  a red flag IMHO. Explicitly passing the observable or callback on your current view model that the binding handler should know of might be better, so you could write e.g.:

```html
<div data-bind="datepicker: { date: myDate, additionalData: someObservable }"></div>
```